# Is the song "25 ans" by Ben Mazué a cover?

Tags: cover

Is there a "original" version of this song [*25 ans*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vVOElTPtGGI) by Ben Mazué?

Comment: Hi Kris, is there a reason to think that this song could be a cover?

Comment: No, im just curious. I love the background of the song but do not understand one word french...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely not. According to the [French wikipedia article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Mazu%C3%A9), Benjamin Mazuet "Ben Mazué" is a singer-songwriter so he mainly performs on his own songs.

Looking at his album [*33 ans*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Ben-Mazu%C3%A9-33-Ans/release/10258530). There is no traces of credits of another artist.

[image: mazué]

He credits himself on this specific song.